# enumeration of character sequence "permutations" (python)

Tags: python, permutation

I have following problem:

There are n=20 characters in the sequence. For each position there is a predefined list of possible characters which can be 1 to m (where m usually is a single digit).

How can I enumerate all possible permutations efficiently?
Or in essence is there some preexisting library (numpy?) that could do that before I try it myself?

Comment: is the list of possible chars the same for all positions, or is it unique per position?

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)?

Comment: Please provide a short example to make your question more explicit

Comment: @Damiaan each position has a different list of possible characters

Comment: Maybe use a dictionary whit values of the possible characters and keys as each position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) seems to offer what I need. I just need to pass it a list of list:

```
itertools.product(*positions)
```

where positions is a list of lists (eg which chars at which positions).

In my case the available options for each position are small and often also just 1 so that keeps the number of possibilities in check but might crash your application if too many get generated.

I then build the final string:

```
for s in itertools.product(*positions):
    result = ''.join(s) 
    results.append(result)
```